# Update all foreign key references

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table student (id, name, address), and student.id reference in few other tables. Lets assume the id is 120 and this id have several other entries in different tables.

Now i want to update the id value to 130 along with all the foreign key references.

One approach I am thinking of a PL/SQL way - doing a metadata query in **all_constraints** table and find the fk reference tables and then run query into all of them for student_id = 130, then update them. Is there any other better options?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not have the `on update cascade` option on referential constraints found in other DB products.

In general, a primary key should be chosen in such a way that it should be almost impossible for it to ever change. If a student id can change in the "normal course of business" then it shouldn't be used as a primary key; perhaps a system-generated sequential number could play that role.

OK, that's for the future. What's done is done. You may find this helpful; please note, I have not used it, I just marked it for myself for future consideration. Good luck!

http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteupdatecascade.html

Comment: The link is unusable